# Higer Order Component Return Value

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I've a higher order component which accepts another component as a parameter and returns the modified component. I'm new to react and I'm confused regarding the `return` statement  in the code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const HOC = (OriginalComp) => {
  function NewComp() {
    const [money, setMoney] = useState(10);
    const handleIncrease = () => {
      setMoney(money * 2);
    };
    return <OriginalComp money={money} handleIncrease={handleIncrease} />;
  }
  return NewComp;
};

export default HOC;
```

I'm having hard time visualising the `return NewComp`  part and the other return. Does the `return NewComp` return previous `return` statement(i.e     `return <OriginalComp money={money} handleIncrease={handleIncrease} />)`, or does it simply return NewComp the function?

Comment: It returns the inner function.

Answer (score 1):

**Concept** : Higher-order component is basically a technique in react for reusing component logic. It is basically a pattern which allow us to use Higher order function.

**Explanation of your code** : *The OriginalComp* is whatever component needs to display onscreen. It means reusable logic will be execute using following line:

```
return <OriginalComp money={money} handleIncrease={handleIncrease} />
```

And finally, the **HOC** function itself is returned at the very bottom of the code snippet (**NewComp**), because, as I said earlier, HOCs are functions that take in one component and return a new, enhanced component.

Some common examples of  HOC's: Common Loader, Common list, etc.

Comment: I understand that , but what i'm confused is regarding the two return statements at the bottom. The one pertaining to NewComp() and the other dealing with HOC function

Comment: NewComp() - This is basically a react functional component, which is returning a required UI component. You can read React functional Component to understand it.
This newComp() is wrapped under HOC, which basically returning your new component. You can refer following document to understand how exactly HOC works - https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html